# Where does KNetAttach store connections?

Tags: ftp, sftp, kde

I am trying to restore old `ftp` and `sftp` connections from old Kubuntu instances. They were set up using the "Add Network Folder" link in Dolphin which is apparently using `knetattach` to establish the connection.

Where is the connection data stored in the file system, so it can be restored?